# I got the following error: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'year'

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, sklearn-pandas

[picture of csv file containing raw data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HNJUO.jpg)   I am trying to plot a scatter graph using an online csv file i downloaded in inorder to get the linear regression.
`%matplotlib inline plt.scatter(df.year, df.income(US), color='red', marker='+')`

Error message reads:
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'year'

Comment: Could you provide an example of the data?

Comment: What about df['year'] and df['income(US)']

Comment: @ mr_mooo_cow....... KeyError: 'year'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`year` is an index, so you can get it like that:

```
plt.scatter(df.index, df["income(US)"], color='red', marker='+')
```

Also you will get an error `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'income'` if you try to get income value like this `df.income(US)`. This is only allowed if the name of the column does not contain special symbols. `df["income(US)"]` is correct.